# Padding byte in Struct

Tags: struct, byte, sizeof, bit-fields

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    struct {
        short a : 2;
        short b : 15;
        char c;
    }abc;
    int main() {
        printf("%d",sizeof(abc));
        return 0;
    }
```

The total size of "abc" is 4 bytes but when printed it is 6 bytes ?
I still don't understand why the size of abc is 6 bytes, `**padding bytes**` are inserted between which `members` of the `struct` ?
How many bytes each `CPU cycle` reads?
Thanks for your respond

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)